# tor and android

Tags: android

I just downloaded  [Fire.onion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=onion.fire&hl=en)+tor from google play.  Will this be acceptable or should I download  tor  alone,  and can I download  it on my android  lollipop tablet?  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to only use the official apps to connect to Tor. If you use a 3rd-party app, nobody can guarantee that it isn't leaking traffic. And if you don't use the official Tor browser, it's easier to track through browser fingerprinting.

Download Orbot for Android here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.torproject.android

And use the Orfox browser with it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.orfox

To use Tor, just open Orbot, long press on the Onion logo to connect, and use the Orfox browser. If you're on a rooted device, you can use transparent proxying to route other apps through Tor, or you can try the experimental VPN feature.

Comment: So I should uninstall the fire. onion+tor?  and use the links you suggested?  I'm  trying to get a vpn connection on this android tablet.  I don't  even know if that's  possible,  tho there's  a place for one in the connections.  And thank you for answering,  and any other help,  I appreciate  it!

Comment: Orbot has an experimental VPN feature you can try.